# how do i set askpass variable?

Tags: 18.04

I keep getting a message telling me to setup SUDO_ASKPASS, bu I don't know how to do it. From what I've read so far it could be upper case or lower case and set in an environment variable or done in sudoers. I would like it to be permanent from one logon to the next. I need the correct syntax and commands. Can you help? I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you give us some context here? AFAIK, `sudo` would only try to invoke `SUDO_ASKPASS` when it's unable to obtain a password interactively from the terminal

Answer (score 5):

WARNING! "could be upper case or lower case" is incorrect. Unix/Linux is case sensitive, which means that `SUDO_ASKPASS` and `sudo_askpass` are different.
WARNING! "set in an environment variable or done in sudoers" is incorrect. You can set the environment variable `SUDO_ASKPASS` or modify `/etc/sudo.conf`.

From `man sudo`:

```
 -A, --askpass
             Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's terminal.
             If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical) helper program
             is executed to read the user's password and output the password to the standard
             output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable is set, it specifies the path
             to the helper program.  Otherwise, if sudo.conf(5) contains a line specifying
             the askpass program, that value will be used.  For example:

                 # Path to askpass helper program
                 Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass

             If no askpass program is available, sudo will exit with an error.
```

Also, from `man sudo.conf`,

```
 The following plugin-agnostic paths may be set in the /etc/sudo.conf file:

 askpass   The fully qualified path to a helper program used to read the user's password when
           no terminal is available.  This may be the case when sudo is executed from a
           graphical (as opposed to text-based) application.  The program specified by
           askpass should display the argument passed to it as the prompt and write the
           user's password to the standard output.  The value of askpass may be overridden by
           the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable.
```

So, you could add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass
```

You could try it for one command,

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass sudo -A id
```

OR, you could uncomment (remove the initial "`#`") on the appropriate line of `sudo.conf` (see `/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples/sudo.conf`)

```
#
# Sudo askpass:
#
# An askpass helper program may be specified to provide a graphical
# password prompt for "sudo -A" support.  Sudo does not ship with its
# own askpass program but can use the OpenSSH askpass.
#
# Use the OpenSSH askpass
#Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass
#
# Use the Gnome OpenSSH askpass
#Path askpass /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass

#
# Sudo askpass:
#
# An askpass helper program may be specified to provide a graphical
# password prompt for "sudo -A" support.  Sudo does not ship with its
# own askpass program but can use the OpenSSH askpass.
#
# Use the OpenSSH askpass
#Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass
#
# Use the Gnome OpenSSH askpass
#Path askpass /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
```

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info. I have already read and tried all of the above information and I finally discovered that I did not have a sudo.conf file in /etc. I found a procedure to create it and once that was done everything started working for me. What I was looking for, as I am so NEW to Linux, was an example of setting SUDO_ASKPASS. I found examples, but they never mentioned sudo.conf.

Answer (score 1):

If somebody using Lubuntu 20.04 should stumble on this, you use:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-askpass
```

Comment: In stock Ubuntu (GNOME) 21.10 needed to `sudo apt install ssh-askpass-gnome`

Comment: @ATutorMe Same thing for me on 20.04, not sure how emilBeBri got it on their system by default

Comment: Not sure either :D